# Click on specific cell and row number in grid using passed parameter (Testcomplete)

Tags: javascript, web, infragistics, testcomplete

I need to create a function to click on an Infragistics WebDataGrid using TestComplete.

Simply clicking on the grid in my main test is easy:

```
page.grid.cell(3, 1).Click();
```

However I want to convert this process into a function, and I am having trouble passing the row and cell numbers in parameters.

My function:

```
function ClickGrid(cellandrow){
page.grid.cell(cellandrow).Click();
}
```

My code that calls the functon:

```
ClickGrid("3, 1");
```

When I run the test, it says "Unable to find cell(3, 1)". So the parameter is being passed correctly, but I just dont think the Click method likes it being sent as a String. I tried to split the cell and row into 2 parameters, then convert them to integers with the following but it resulted in the same "Unable to find cell(3, 1)"

```
    function ClickGrid(cell, row){
    aqConvert.StrToInt(cell)        
    aqConvert.StrToInt(row);
    page.grid.cell(cell + ", " + row).Click();
    }
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution

```
page.grid.cell(cell,row).Click();
```